# Should I create a new Promise in each class method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

I would like to utilize the Promises in my class methods. In [Promise antipatterns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/11002836) I read that creating a new promise for each new function is considered to be bad.

However, I don't want to return un-related promises in my project, so I thought of doing something like this:

```
class MyClass {

  async getToken() {
    return new Promise(
      (resolve, reject) => {
        // . . .
        const token_str = '<response_from_http_request>';
        resolve(token_str);
      }
    )
  }

  async doSomething(token) {
    return new Promise(
      (resolve, reject) => {
        const result = // . . .
        resolve(result);
      }
    )
  }

  async doAnotherSomething(token) {
    return new Promise(
      (resolve, reject) => {
        const result = // . . .
        resolve(result);
      }
    )
  }

}
```

Then I would use it like this:

```
let instance = new MyClass();

(async () => {
    const token = await instance.getToken();

    const result1 = await instance.doSomething(token);
    console.log(result1);

    const result2 = await instance.doAnotherSomething(token);
    console.log(result2);

})();
```

Does this seem like a valid way to do this, or is this an antipattern too? And if so, how can I avoid writing code like this?

---

**EDIT:** What if I need to make several sequential http calls, perform some actions on the results and then return a Promise based on it?

The way I understand, if I don't make a *new* Promise, I have to return the one made by the `got.js` library, which includes the http response data.

Instead, I want to return a Promise which contains the result of my class method.

Example:

```
  async getCityWeather( city_name ) {
    return new Promise(
      (resolve, reject) => {

        // get the city id based on its name
        const city_id = await got(`https://my-api/getCityIdByName/${city_name}`);

        // now get the weather info for the city with id `cityid`
        const weather_info = await got(`https://my-api/weatherById/${city_id}`);

        // make an object to return
        const temperature = {
          weather_info.temp_min,
          weather_info.temp_max,
        }

        resolve(temperature);

        // ... all error handling are omitted

      }
    )
  }
```

I don't want to return a Promise that contains *got.js* return values, I want to return *my* values based on the http request calls.

Comment: What exactly are all those `// . . .`? Unless you are doing anything asynchronous in there, you should not use promises at all.

Comment: Sidenote: Your `result1` and `result2` only depend on the token. You then can do: `const [result1, result2] = await Promise.all([instance.doSomething(token), instance.doAnotherSomething(token)]);` to not cause blocking.

Comment: @k0pernikus Neither way causes blocking in the sense that it blocks the thread. They are wasteful by virtue of the fact that one needs to wait of the other though.

Comment: @Bergi I forgot to mention, in all `// . . .` marked lines I'm doing async [got.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54486324/11002836) calls.

Comment: @k0pernikus Very good observation! But doesn't this fail to populate a `result*` variable if the other one fails? At least that's what I understand from `Promise.all()`. In any case, using `await` where the calls are independent is wasteful as @Nik said.

Comment: @ConfusedGuy Then yes, you definitely should avoid the `new Promise` constructor antipattern

Comment: @Bergi I added a note to the end of my question explaining my understanding, please correct me if I'm mistaken on how the `Promise` value works when chaining them. I want to pass my _own_ results instead of the one made by `got.js` library.

Comment: Use `then` or `await` for that. You don't need any `new Promise` for this. See the `getFooBarBaz` method in the answer below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`async` functions *always* return a `Promise`.

A function/method will return a Promise under the following circumstances:

- You explicitly created and returned a Promise from it's body.
- You returned a Promise that exists outside the method.
- You marked it as `async`.

Since you can `await` a Promise and `instance.doSomething` is already an async-marked method, you can await it without needing to explicitly return a Promise.

Simply `return` it's result like you would in a regular synchronous method.

> I don't want to return un-related promises in my project...

Unless you're actually doing something asynchronous in your method (accessing the file system, database calls, timers etc...), you **don't** need to wrap it in a `Promise`, nor `await` it when you need a result.

The most usual case where you actually need to wrap something in a `Promise` is if you have an asynchronous function that works using [*callbacks*](http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/03/understanding-error-first-callbacks-in-node-js/) but you want to use it as a `Promise`.

```js
// plain old callback-style asynchronous functions:
const getFooViaCallback = callback => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    callback('foo')
  }, 150)
}

const getBarViaCallback = callback => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    callback('bar')
  }, 150)
}

class Foo {
  constructor() {}
  
  getFooViaPromise() {
    // wrap callback-style code in a Promise
    // so we can await it.
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      getFooViaCallback(result => {
        resolve(result)
      })
    })
  }

  getBarViaPromise() {
    // wrap callback-style code in a Promise
    // so we can await it.
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      getBarViaCallback(result => {
        resolve(result)
      })
    })
  }
  
  getBaz() {
    // no reason to wrap this in a Promise,
    // since it's a synchronous method.
    return 'baz'
  }
  
  async getFooBarBaz() {
    const foo = await this.getFooViaPromise()
    const bar = await this.getBarViaPromise()
    const baz = this.getBaz()

    return foo + ',' + bar + ',' + baz
  }
}

;(async() => {
  const foo = new Foo()
  
  const result = await foo.getFooBarBaz()
  console.log('foo.getFooBarBaz() result: ', result)
})()
```

I've ommited error handling in the above snippet for brevity but you should use `throw` in `async`-marked methods to raise errors. It's the equivalent of calling `.reject()` within a Promise.

Comment: 1. Can you explain your first point? How can I use `resolve()` and `reject()` without using `new Promise()` in my code?

Comment: It's the other way round, isn't it? If you're returning a promise you don't need to make the method async too.

Comment: 2. I'm using [got.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54486324/11002836) which requires the `async` context to work.

Comment: @ConfusedGuy functions marked with `async` can use `return` much like a synchronous function. That functions much like calling `resolve` within a `Promise`. Gimme 5' and I'll also post a code snippet that explains this.

Comment: @Andy I didn't test this, so sorry for asking _BUT_ does this mean that if I return a Promise, I can use `await` in the method context?

Comment: @NikKyriakides Oh, I understand. I presume `throw Error("Something")` should be used instead of `reject( new Error("Something") )`, then?

Comment: Yes. You can return a promise and use `async`. Something [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/8g3La2so/1/) perhaps.

Comment: @ConfusedGuy That's entirely correct, `async` functions must use `throw` to raise errors.

Comment: @ConfusedGuy No, you don't need an "async context" to make got.js work. It returns promises, that's all. You only need an `async` function context when you want to `await` such a promise.

Comment: @Andy It works both ways. If you explicitly return a promise, you don't need to make the function `async`, but conversely, if you make the function `async` you don't have to return a promise since an `async` function implicitly returns a promise that gets resolved with whatever you do return (or rejected with whatever you throw)